# create a specific hash (dynamic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can create a hash like this in a cycle ?

```
User.items.each do |m|
          ......
```

Result:

```
 test = [{:name => 'Unit 1', :price => "10.00"},
                {:name => 'Unit 2', :price => "12.00"},
                {:name => 'Unit 3', :price => "14.00"}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to return hashes that you build.

Assuming your `Item` resource responds to `name` and `price`, it would look like

```
test = User.items.map do |m|
  { 
    name: m.name,
    price: m.price
  }
end
```

Comment: I wanna extract name and price from active record and create a hash with the name "test".

Comment: On which model do your name and price attributes exist?

Comment: In my model (active record) name and price attributes dont exist.

Comment: I see, you probably don't have nearly enough infrastructure to achieve what you want. I'd suggest reading up on [migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) and  [models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) to make your system have the data you're trying to extract. Then, use my answer to your best ability.

Answer (score 1):

You also can do like this:

```
Item.connection.select_all("select name, price from items where user_id = xxxxx;")
```

you will get an array containing hash, like this:

```
[{"name"=>"xxx", "price"=> xxx},{}......]
```

Comment: You can pass a relation to `select_all`, i.e. `Item.connection.select_all(Item.select(:name, :price).where(...))`. Furthermore, I think `select_all` will return a [`ActiveRecord::Result`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html), so you'll have to call `to_hash` to get an array of hashes.

Comment: @Stefan  select_all  will return an array of hash directly, you doesn't need to use `to_hash`

Comment: Not according to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all)

Comment: @Stefan `select_all` has been modified for the newest rails versions, I am using the old rails version 3.2.5(http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_all)